# re-size the modal dialog in bootstrap dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Modal Popup (Bootstrap) which displays content based on the user selection

- [I've used this as my reference, Also added this to my script section in the aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152629/2260496)

This is the javascript code that i've used to check for the users selection

```
PlayerMP.getFunctionalDetails = function (type, UserID, SessionID, SessionNo) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: PlayerMP.URL,
    data: "rt=4&type=" + type + "&UserID=" + UserID + "&SessionID=" + SessionID + "&SessionNo=" + SessionNo,
    success: function (FunctionalSplitsJS) {
        if (FunctionalSplitsJS.indexOf("SessionExpired=1", 0) == -1) {

            $("#divFunctionalDetails").html(FunctionalSplitsJS);
            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    $("#divFunctionalsSplit");      //the table goes out of the modal window                           
                     break;
                case 2:
                    TallyFunctionalSheet();
                    $("#divFunctionalsSplit"); 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $("#divFunctionalsSplit"); 
                    break;
            }                

             $("#divFunctionalsSplit").modal('show');
        }
        else
            window.location.href = "../Login.aspx?SessionExpired=1";
    }
});
}
```

- The first case has a table which is supposed to be displayed inside the modal popup but the table goes outside the modal window (there is a problem with the width of the modal window but the `table-responsive` seem to be working) But when i resize the browser to match the width of the tablet the table/modal auto resizes to match each other.
- The width of the 2nd and the 3rd case's of the modal seem to work fine.

This is the code for the modal window thats being called

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="divFunctionalsSplit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">  
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content"> 
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div id="divFunctionalDetails"></div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

- **Fullscreen Browser**
  [image: Full screen image]
- **Resized Browser**
  [image: Resized Image]

Comment: @FlorentHemmi that link was my reference. i've already done that. Still no go

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out???

Comment: nope sorry @Luminous.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to resize Twitter Bootstrap modal dynamically based on the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content) that was posted and answered 6 months prior to this.

Comment: @MikeTeeVee I have linked the exact question in my post as reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default Bootstrap sets the width of the `.modal-dialog` to 600px (large screens above 768 px) or auto(small screens). The code below overrides this:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({width:'auto',
                               height:'auto', 
                              'max-height':'100%'});
});
```

(based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152629/2260496)

To make it more dynamically you will need to calculate the width (jQuery `width()` or `innerwidth()`)of your table and set the width of the `modal-dialog` according it.

See: http://bootply.com/88364

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me atleast:

```
.modal-dialog{
    position: relative;
    display: table; /* <-- This makes the trick */
    overflow-y: auto;    
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 300px;   
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly. No need to for any javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Change this to your code

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 95%">
```

and this

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `display: table;` inside the div holding the modal it'll resize accordingly. My modal is draggable and doesn't resize when you change the size of the browser, but this is the only workable solution I found for dynamic modal sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-dialog').addClass('modal-lg');
});
```

Comment: please add explanation.

Comment: Looks like he's saying to add the `modal-lg` class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the issue was not the modal itself. I added an ID to each element inside  of the  and via CSS just add a width:100% to all of them.

It worked for me.

Comment: this can be used as a dirty fix.