# Bootstrap resize height of modal dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When i show my modal, i've only inputtext and button, the scenario is :

When i click in button, i search a result in terms of what i've write in input text, te result are displayed in table belowed the button.

My table is displayed but outside of the modal (the height of modal doesnt change)

I've tried to apply this solution but it doesnt work :

[re-size the modal dialog in bootstrap dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396631/re-size-the-modal-dialog-in-bootstrap-dynamically)

here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="dialogEtablissement" role="dialog" class="modal in" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                <form method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal clearfix">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Recherche d'un établissement</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-content modal-content-correct">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                <dt>Nom de l'établissement contient :</dt>
                                <dd><input type="text" id="idNomEtab" class="form-control" style="width:40%;display:inline;"/></dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
                            <a id="idSearchEtablissement" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:searchEtablissement()">Rechercher</a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="grid"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <input type="button" name="Fermer" value="Fermer" onclick="$('#dialogEtablissement').modal('hide');" class="btn btn-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS :**

```
function showModalEtablissement(){
    $('#dialogEtablissement').modal('show');
    $('#dialogEtablissement').on('show', function () {
        $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
            width:'auto',
            height:'auto', 
            'max-height':'100%'
        });
    });
}
```

And the result are added here :

```
$("#grid").append('<table class="table">');
$("#grid").append('<thead>');
$("#grid").append('<tr><th>Nom</th><th>Rue</th><th>Code Postal</th><th>Ville</th></tr>');
$("#grid").append('</thead>');

$("#grid").append('<tbody>');
for (i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").append('<tr id="' +liste[i].id+ '">');
    $('#grid').append('<td>' + liste[i].nom+ '</td>');
    $('#grid').append('<td>' + liste[i].adresseLibelle+ '</td>');
    $('#grid').append('<td>' + liste[i].adresseCodePostal+ '</td>');
    $('#grid').append('<td>' + liste[i].adresseVille+ '</td>');
    $("#grid").append('</tr>');
}
$("#grid").append('</tbody>');
$("#grid").append('</table>');
```

Comment: try putting in a <div> with a sertain ID and some javascript to display the table inside the div tags. with the div that has that ID

Comment: The div with id exist : <div id="grid"></div>

Comment: I see but you still have to write something so that it gets displayed in there.

Comment: I change the place of the div before footer of modal, i get my table but i dont have the scroll

Comment: if you mean scrollbar look up how to enable it. or increase height of the div onclick

Comment: I add this after show modal but i think the style doesnt change : $(this).find('.modal-content').css({
      width:'auto',
            height:'300px', 
      'max-height':'200px',
      overflow: auto,
      background: green
     });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137560/discussion-between-pasja95-and-h-brendan).