# Bootstrap modal won't stretch to fit content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The modal, despite the same thing working fine on other pages, won't stretch to fit it's content and ends up too short. The only thing that seems to fix it is adding another `div` or `p` element with any content below it and I'd rather not have to do that.

HTML:

```
<!-- Donate modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="donate" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="donateToDev" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="donateTitle">Donate</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="text-center">There's nothing to unlock by donating, but you will be considered awesome by the dev! Who doesn't like being awesome?</p>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div style="float:left;display:inline;">
                            PAYPAL
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right;display:inline;">
                            <p class="bold text-center">Or you could donate with <a href="http://dogecoin.com">Dogecoin</a>:
                            <p class="code">doge donate address here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS:

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.text-center { text-align: center; }
```

Result:

[image: The dogecoin address line is below where the modal ends, and if you add content to the Paypal one, it'll do it there, too.]

Comment: Possibly you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content?rq=1

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq unfortunately not - adding what the answer provided didn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not clearing your floats. To quickly solve the issue you could add "clearfix" to the div with the "text-center" class.

Read about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
  <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y:auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another stylesheet hindering with the bootstrap.css file.
try playing with the inspect element of the browser

or

try this

```
.modal-dialog{overflow:visible;min-height:100%!important;}
```

you can try using "!important", to override whatever is making it happen so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a style of

.modal-body{
height:100%
}

it works for me :)