# Remove blank space from right side of a page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that will popout in a modal, but I need it centralized so I can decrease the size of the modal.
This is what I got so far:

http://s7.postimg.org/ierno14ln/2015_08_06_114302.png

I seems like that space is beeing "reserved" for column that I am not using.
What could I be using so I can decrease the size of it?
Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<div id="div_pedidoWeb" class="form-inline modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">                                                  
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Pedido Web</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="modal-body">  
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_usuario">Usu&aacute;rio:</label>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_usuario" id="txt_usuario" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_nr_pedido">N&uacute;mero Pedido WEB:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_nr_pedido" id="txt_nr_pedido" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_situacao">Situa&ccedil;&atilde;o:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_situacao" id="txt_situacao" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_tipo_pedido">Tipo de Pedido:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_tipo_pedido" id="txt_tipo_pedido" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37"  />    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_cod_representante">Representante:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input name="txt_cod_representante" id="txt_cod_representante" type="text" class="form-control" size="1" maxlength="37"  />
                            <img src="lupa.png" name="img_zoom_representante"  id="img_zoom_representante">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_desc_representante1" id="txt_desc_representante1" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input name="txt_desc_representante2" id="txt_desc_representante2" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" style="width: 100%" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_cod_cliente">Cliente:</label>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input name="txt_cod_cliente" id="txt_cod_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" size="1" maxlength="37"  />
                            <img src="lupa.png" name="img_zoom_cliente"  id="img_zoom_cliente">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_desc_cliente1" id="txt_desc_cliente1" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" style="margin-right: 126px;" />
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-md-3">                  
                            <input name="txt_desc_cliente2" id="txt_desc_cliente2" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37" style="width: 100%" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_cnpj">CNPJ:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input name="txt_cnpj" id="txt_cnpj" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="37" style="width: 100%" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label style="padding-top: 12px" for="txa_endereco">Endere&ccedil;o:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea name="txa_endereco" id="txa_endereco" type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 100%"></textarea>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_pedido_cliente">Pedido Cliente:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_pedido_cliente" id="txt_pedido_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" maxlength="37"  />  
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_moeda">Moeda:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_moeda" id="txt_moeda" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37"  />    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_emissao">Emiss&atilde;o:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_emissao" id="txt_emissao" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" maxlength="37"  />    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_data_entrega">Data de Entrega:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_data_entrega" id="txt_data_entrega" type="text" class="form-control" size="20" maxlength="37"  />  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="sl_destino_mercadoria">Destino Mercadoria:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <select name="sl_destino_mercadoria" id="sl_destino_mercadoria" class="form-control">
                                <option value="00">Selecione</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_cod_pagamento">Cond. de Pagamento:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 8%">
                            <input name="txt_cod_pagamento" id="txt_cod_pagamento" type="text" class="form-control" size="1"/>
                            <img src="lupa.png" name="img_zoom_pagamento"  id="img_zoom_pagamento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input name="txt_desc_pagamento" id="txt_desc_pagamento" type="text" class="form-control" size="16"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_cod_tab_precos">Tabela Pre&ccedil;os:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input name="txt_cod_tab_precos" id="txt_cod_tab_precos" type="text" class="form-control" size="5"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input name="txt_desc_tab_precos" id="txt_desc_tab_precos" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label style="padding-top: 12px" for="txa_obs_cliente">Observa&ccedil;&otilde;es do Cliente:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea name="txa_obs_cliente" id="txa_obs_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-align">
                            <label for="txt_email">Email:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input name="txt_email" id="txt_email" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="37" style="width: 100%" />   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the CSS we cant do much, since bootstrap can be customised. It is most likely caused by top-buffer or container-fluid, modal-body. With a incorrect padding or margin. text-align is not the standard either. You also do no state the grid size. From this, it seems to be 8 but the default is 12. I tend to use 24.

Comment: container-fluid is a standard class from bootstrap.css. top-buffer class only add a margin-top:20px on the inputs and text-align only aplies a text-align: left; on the labels.

Comment: #div_pedidoWeb {width:100%}

Comment: @BradHouston Doesnt produce any effect

Answer (score 0):

[I believe this is what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content) . Adding that code to any style css after your bootstrap library will create the modals to be fluid and hence they would resize according to your content.

Comment: That is not what im looking for. What I want is to remove the blank space even when the form is not inside the modal. I posted the image to be be easier to understand my problem, but the issue its not the modal size itself, its that the form is more on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I wanted. I discovered that bootstrap col-*-* sets specify differents widths depending on what the value of col-*-* always trying to fill 100% width. In my case, it was applying 16,6% of width in each column so the total was 66,4. The blank space in the right side was the others 33,6% left. I solved my problem using col-md-3 in all columns so the total columns was 12 (4*25=100%).