# Angular Bootstrap Modal not Scaling

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implemented a modal:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>asjdkljasldjal;sdjakl;djal;jqwjeo8qajeoqjeoqoweuq90euq0uew0qjwe09quwe9qu0equ09weu8q90uwe0que98que9quew89que9quw9eq9weuq98eualsnkdakjsd</h3>
    </div>
</script>
```

However, the box is not scaling with text as seen here:

[image: Modal isn't scaling]

From the angular bootstrap documentation, this stuff should automagically scale. Is there an option I need to enable? Or is there something I missed in the implementation?

Comment: The problem is your long, unbroken line of text

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: @Phil I used a large string as an example. My actual content is not only a string. It can be video or an image. Is there a way to make the modal expand to meet its content?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The modal width is determined by the `size` attribute which directly relates to the CSS class applied. You might be able to do something with CSS but I doubt it's going to be easy. What led you to believe it would scale dynamically?

Comment: @Phil If you go to the angular bootstrap website: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and look at their modal, it scales with text/image/whatever you throw at it

Comment: Err, does it? The only thing that changes the size is clicking the different buttons (ie *"Large modal"*, *"Small modal"*, etc)

Comment: @Phil Actually, after playing with the plunker more, I see that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS: `word-wrap: break-word;` on your long unbroken word.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Comment: I used a large string as an example. If I were to say, use a video or an image, the modal would not stretch either

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content#

Comment: I saw that question, however, angular bootstrap and jquery don't play well together. See https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Comment: I agree. But you wouldn't require Jquery at all. We can add an event listener in plain Javascript using **element.addEventListener**