# Img is not fully displayed in the pop up

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button that shows an image in a pop up. If the picture is horizontal it's not totally displayed . I want to make the dialog, where the picture will be displayed , takes the size of the picture dynamically so whatever it's size it will be fully shown.

this is my backbone view:

```
    View.Proof = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template : pictureTpl,
        initialize : function(options) {
            this.parentModel = options;
            this.parentModel.documentBaseUrl = '../services/api';               
        },
        templateHelpers : function() {
            return {
                documentBaseUrl : this.parentModel.documentBaseUrl
            };
        },
        onShow : function(view) {
            this.listenTo(view, ".close", this.onClose);
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            $(this.$el.children()[0]).modal('show');
            //$("#myModal2").modal('show'); 
        },
        onClose: function() {
            console.log('hide popup');
            //$("#myModal2").modal('hide');
            $(this.$el.children()[0]).modal('hide');
        }
    });
```

And this is my picture.tpl (pictureTpl):

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item  active ">
                    <img style="border: 1px solid #666" src="<%- documentBaseUrl %>/pictures/<%- id %>/file" alt="folder" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
  After deep research i found this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content) so i've edited my view as below:

```
            onShow : function(view) {
            this.listenTo(view, ".close", this.onClose);
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            $(this.$el.children()[0]).modal('show', function () {
                   $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
                          width:'auto', //probably not needed
                          height:'auto', //probably not needed 
                          'max-height':'100%'
                   });
            });
```

But this solution is not working for me

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want the button to expand depending on the img inside it?

Comment: @Aziz no the img is not shown on the button but in dialog as a pop up. The button is used to show the pop up that displays the img in the picture.tpl

Comment: can you show us how the dialog looks like? ideally a jsfiddle demo

Comment: css..? Please share an [mcve]

Comment: @TJ i meant by css if there is a solution using css to the dialog to take dynamically the size of the picture

Comment: @juniorengineer I meant you should share the css so that we can reproduce and debug the issue...

Comment: Share a working example please.