# Difficulty setting height of Bootstrap Modal Container with changes in child elements containing ui-view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

> Hi, I really was trying to understand why my initial modal step fails to initialize at the right height. My angular directive for setting the parent containing div to the right height does not work on the first modal step. Why? Also, I am using external files and feel that the following plunker link is a better demo of this problem. Basically, I am using a bootstrap modal and inserting a ui-view whose route is controlled by ui-router. No big deal, but the parent containing height collapses so I am using jquery to set the height of the containing div so the footer moves down appropriately. It fails to work on the first modal step and I am at a loss for what else to do.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qpFfckmh8ExbRlqzROhM?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
 .state("step1", {
  url: "/step1",
  templateUrl: "step1.html"
 })
 .state("step2", {
  url: "/step2",
  templateUrl: "step2.html"

 })
 .state("step3", {
  url: "/step3",
  templateUrl: "step3.html"

 });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

app.controller("appController", ["$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {
 $scope.clickJoin = function($state) {
  $location.path("step1");

  showHidePrevNextBtns();
 }
 
 $scope.clickNext = function($state) {
  if($location.path() === "/step2") {
    $location.path("step3");

  }
  if($location.path() === "/step1") {
    $location.path("step2");
 
  } 
  showHidePrevNextBtns();
 };
 
 $scope.clickPrevious = function($state) {
  if($location.path() === "/step2") {
   $location.path("step1");

  }
  if($location.path() === "/step3") {
   $location.path("step2");

  }
  showHidePrevNextBtns();
 };
 
 function showHidePrevNextBtns() {
  if($location.path() === "/step2" || $location.path() === "/step3") $scope.previousBtn = true;
  else $scope.previousBtn = false;

  if($location.path() === "/step1" || $location.path() === "/step2") $scope.nextBtn = true;
  else $scope.nextBtn = false;
 }
}]);

app.directive("banner", function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).parent().height($(element).height());
    }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.modal-container {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-step {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#status-buttons div { 
 color:#FFF; 
 display:inline-block; 
 font-size:12px; 
 margin-right:10px; 

 text-transform:uppercase; 
}

#status-buttons span{ 
 color:#000000; 
 display:inline-block; 
 font-size:12px; 
 margin-right:10px; 

 text-transform:uppercase; 
 
 background:#ffffff; display:block; height:30px; margin:0 auto 10px; padding-top:5px; width:30px; 
    border-radius:50%; 
}

#status-buttons span.active   { 
 background-color:#C32026; 
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

 <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
   
  <div class="btn-group dropdown">
   <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" ng-click="clickJoin()"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Join</button>
  </div>
          
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="joinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" >
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title italic" id="myModalLabel">Become a Member Today!</h4>
     </div>
             
     <!-- NAVIGATION -->
     <div class="page-header text-center" >
      <h2>Step</h2>
      <div id="status-buttons">
       <div><span >1</span></div>
       <div><span>2</span></div>
       <div><span>3</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
             
     <div class="modal-body" style="border: red solid 1px">
      <div class="modal-container" style="border: blue solid 1px;">
       <div class="modal-step" banner ui-view style="border: black solid 1px"></div>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <br />
     
     <br />
     <br />
             
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
       <button type="button" id="previousBtn" ng-show="previousBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickPrevious()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
       <button type="button" id="nextBtn" ng-show="nextBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickNext()">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
       <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>        
  </div>
 </div>     

 
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The demo is working fine with the height

Comment: No. Step1 opens and the modal-container div is collapsed. You can see it very well with the blue border.

Comment: Yes, I understand, But I see it coming up correctly, I am using Chrome.

Comment: ahhh now I see it, It is happening randomly to me..

Comment: it corrects after initially loading. you have to make sure you are refreshing your browser or even better stop and start the plunker.

Comment: thanks for taking a look @Reddy

Answer (score 0):

Adding this css to your modal body will fix the issue.

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I added it to the app.css and it isn't fixing it. can you give me a plunker?

Comment: I had fixed my similar issue this way, And as I told you your plunker works well too.. Now I am not able to reproduce the issue at all.. However this link would help you solve your issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/zZnojKCaeeiTUb42FW5I?p=preview this is the only way I got it to work

Comment: Well if thats fixed then good news!!! Let me delete my answer. But you can add your solution as answer here so it will be useful for somebody else

Comment: you don't have to delete it. thank you for taking the time to provide my the link @Reddy

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal-step {
  position: relative;
  display: table; //important 
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zZnojKCaeeiTUb42FW5I?p=preview

> adding this to the app.css is the only way I got it to work