# Setting height automatically instead of displaying scrollbar in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

There is two inputs on a `Bootstrap Modal` and they are display/hide by `dropdownlist` value. I hide the scrollbar of the modal and want to the modal increase / decrease its height automatically as the dropdownlist's selected index changes. Although I tried to use **"height: auto !important;"** in every `div` on the modal, it cannot be changed automatically (but changed when I set the height as pixel value). So, is it possible to do this automatically?

```
<style>
    .modal {        
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
</style>



<!-- /.modal -->
<div id='accountModal' class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id='accountModalContainer' class="modal-dialog" 
            style="width:600px !important; max-height:1000px; height:auto !important;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                    
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Can you provide us what you have done so far

Comment: @Abhijeet I added my code to the question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add your whole code related to modal and elaborate what you want the final output

Comment: As I use several partialview, it is a little bit difficult for me but the problem can be solved when using **display: table** in modal class. however, in that case the modal cannot be opened on the center of the screen and opened left side even if I use **position:absolute** property. Any idea to open it on the center of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for those who encounter the same problem:

```
<style>
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    display: table; /* This is the most important feature */
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    width:100%; 
}
</style>
```

For more information look at Amit Shah's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content) page.

Answer (score -1):

look at this please.

I have made a little tweak for the .modal-body class with additional css.

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: auto;
}
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 225px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ma4zn5gv/178/