# KonvaJS - Making it responsive with Bootstrap Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, konvajs

Below is a KonvaJS project where you can add stickers to an image. However, it has a fixed width and a fixed height.

Now because the sizes are fixed, it won't work with anything response, like a bootstrap modal.

Here is my attempt following a KonvaJS response guide, [see here.](https://craftblock.me/koa/stickers-responsive/) and the [guide here.](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Responsive_Canvas.html)

In my attempt, after I upload the image, my code can't get the new width of the modal as it returns 0, so it can't calculate it for the size of the canvas.

How can I make the canvas responsive?

```js
function centreRectShape(shape) {
  shape.x((stage.getWidth() - shape.getWidth()) / 2);
  shape.y((stage.getHeight() - shape.getHeight()) / 2);
}

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas-container',
  width: 650,
  height: 300
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var bgRect = new Konva.Rect({
  width: stage.getWidth(),
  height: stage.getHeight(),
  fill: 'gold',
  opacity: 0.1
});
layer.add(bgRect);

var uploadedImage = new Konva.Image({
  draggable: false
});

layer.add(uploadedImage);

// make an object to keep things tidy - not strictly needed, just being tidy
function addSticker(imgUrl){

  // make the sticker image object
  var stickerObj = new Konva.Image({
    x: 240,
    y: 20,
    width: 93,
    height: 104,
    name: 'sticker',
    draggable: true
    });
  layer.add(stickerObj);
  
  // make the sticker image loader html element
  var stickerImage = new Image();
  stickerImage.onload = function() {
    stickerObj.image(stickerImage);
    layer.draw();
  };
  
  
  
  stickerObj.on('transformstart', function(){
    undoBefore = makeUndo(this);
  })
  stickerObj.on('transformend', function(){
    var undoAfter = makeUndo(this);
    addUndo(123, undoBefore, undoAfter)
  })
  // assigning the URL of the image starts the onload
  stickerImage.src = imgUrl;

}

imgObj = new Image();

imgObj.onload = function() {

  uploadedImage.image(imgObj);

  var padding = 20;
  var w = imgObj.width;
  var h = imgObj.height;

  var targetW = stage.getWidth() - (2 * padding);
  var targetH = stage.getHeight() - (2 * padding);

  var widthFit = targetW / w;
  var heightFit = targetH / h;
  var scale = (widthFit > heightFit) ? heightFit : widthFit;

  w = parseInt(w * scale, 10);
  h = parseInt(h * scale, 10);

  uploadedImage.size({
    width: w,
    height: h
  });
  centreRectShape(uploadedImage);
  layer.draw();
}

imgObj.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/787961/pexels-photo-787961.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260';

$('.sticker').on('click', function() {
  var theSticker = addSticker($(this).attr('src'));
  toggle(true);
  toggle(false);
});

var vis = false;
$('#toggler').on('click', function(){
  toggle(vis);
})

function undoData(opts){
  this.x = opts.x;
  this.y = opts.y;
  this.width = opts.w;
  this.height = opts.h;
  this.rotation = opts.r;
}

var undoBefore;  
function makeUndo(shape){
  return  new undoData({x:shape.getX(), y: shape.getY(), w: shape.getWidth(), h: shape.getHeight(), r: shape.getRotation() })   
}

var undoList = [];
function addUndo(shapeId, before, after){
  undoList.push({id: shapeId, before: before, after: after});
  console.log(undoList[undoList.length - 1])
}

function toggle(isVisible){

  if (!isVisible){
    
    var shapes = stage.find('.sticker');
    shapes.each(function(shape) { 

      var imgRotator = new Konva.Transformer({
        node: shape,
        name: 'stickerTransformer',
        keepRatio: true,
        enabledAnchors: ['top-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right']
      });
      layer.add(imgRotator);
    })
    vis = true;
  }
  else {
    var shapes = stage.find('.stickerTransformer');
    shapes.each(function(shape) { 
      shape.remove();
    })
    vis=false;
    }
  layer.draw();
  $('#toggler').html((vis ? 'Toggle Off' : 'Toggle On'));
}
```

```css
html,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

#image-editor {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.stickers {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: #eee;
}

.stickers>img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
                <div id="image-editor">
                    <div id="canvas-container"></div>
                    <div class="stickers">
                        <img class="sticker" src="https://craftblock.me/koa/fb-upload-clone/stickers/sticker%20(1).png" alt="Sticker" width="62px">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So let me try to explain the issue a bit more: [Check out the live version of my attempt of making it responsive.](https://craftblock.me/koa/stickers-responsive/)

[image]

As you can see, after trying to load the image into the canvas, the modal pops up but the canvas fails to resize.

Here's the JS to that:

```
    /**
 * Image Editor
 */

var stageWidth = 1000;
var stageHeight = 1000;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'canvas-container',
    width: stageWidth,
    height: stageHeight
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var bgRect = new Konva.Rect({
    width: stage.getWidth(),
    height: stage.getHeight(),
    fill: 'gold',
    opacity: 0.1
});
layer.add(bgRect);

var uploadedImage = new Konva.Image({
    draggable: false
});

layer.add(uploadedImage);

imgObj.onload = function () {

    uploadedImage.image(imgObj);

    var padding = 20;
    var w = imgObj.width;
    var h = imgObj.height;

    var targetW = stage.getWidth() - (2 * padding);
    var targetH = stage.getHeight() - (2 * padding);

    var widthFit = targetW / w;
    var heightFit = targetH / h;
    var scale = (widthFit > heightFit) ? heightFit : widthFit;

    w = parseInt(w * scale, 10);
    h = parseInt(h * scale, 10);

    uploadedImage.size({
        width: w,
        height: h
    });
    centreRectShape(uploadedImage);
    layer.draw();
}

$('.sticker').on('click', function () {
    addSticker($(this).attr('src'));
});

fitStageIntoParentContainer();
window.addEventListener('resize', fitStageIntoParentContainer);

function centreRectShape(shape) {
    shape.x((stage.getWidth() - shape.getWidth()) / 2);
    shape.y((stage.getHeight() - shape.getHeight()) / 2);
}

function addSticker(imgUrl) {
    var stickerObj = new Konva.Image({
        x: 240,
        y: 20,
        width: 93,
        height: 104,
        draggable: true
    });
    var stickerImage = new Image();
    stickerImage.onload = function () {
        stickerObj.image(stickerImage);
        centreRectShape(stickerObj);
        layer.draw();
    };
    stickerImage.src = imgUrl;
    layer.add(stickerObj);
    addModifiers(stickerObj);
}

function addModifiers(obj) {
    var imgRotator = new Konva.Transformer({
        node: obj,
        keepRatio: true,
        enabledAnchors: ['top-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right']
    });
    layer.add(imgRotator);
}

function fitStageIntoParentContainer() {
    var container = document.querySelector("edit-image-modal");

    // now we need to fit stage into parent
    var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    // to do this we need to scale the stage
    var scale = containerWidth / stageWidth;


    stage.width(stageWidth * scale);
    stage.height(stageHeight * scale);
    stage.scale({
        x: scale,
        y: scale
    });
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: You are posting too much code that does not relate to the issue. Someone will shortly mention posting a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue. Not me though.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat true but kinda? I would add the responsive attempt here (that's already linked in the post) but then it wouldn't work because of the upload script?

Comment: Let me get my bearings straight - are we talking about the konvajs stage not being reactive ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat after uploading an image, I need to recalculate the size of canvas with the new canvas size, as before it was 0, but after uploading the image it's a different size. It's not being reactive to after I add the image to imgObj.src.

Comment: Can you check that comment - not making total sense to me? Is this about triggering a resize after the image file is uploaded ? For positioning the image on the canvas ?

Comment: Edited the question @VanquishedWombat

Comment: Thank you for the video. Do you think this could be an issue re the sizes of some elements are not available from the DOM until the element is visible ? I often find that funky fade-in animation affects my measuring of elements this way. Part of the law-of-unintended-consequences of visibility transition effects. To confirm put a setTimeout() around the call to the measuring code - say 3 secs delay to be sure.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I think it's because it's not calculating the image yet, I'm inserting the image into imgObj incorrectly.

Comment: If it was me I would be interested if fitStageIntoParentContainer() was running, and if it was what the width & height of element edit-image-modal are. Can you console.log them and see what you get ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181895/discussion-between-vanquished-wombat-and-kinx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique you have used to listen for 'resize' on the page will work for the main window but likely not for the modal. You can confirm that by some simple console.log() output.

You need to use the bootstrap event on('show.bs.modal') to catch when the modal is shown, which is when you really want to fire the call to fitStageIntoParentContainer();

See [this SO post for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152275/how-to-resize-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dynamically-based-on-the-content). It is not a duplicate but covers the bootstrap modal event.

In case that question is erased, you should be heading for something like:

```
$('your_modal_element_selector').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       fitStageIntoParentContainer();
});
```